# Writing Yahoo! Bot: Why can't I fetch a web page on Yahoo! mail with help of PHP?

Tags: php

I want to write a bot that fetches my mail on Yahoo! but my first problem is I can't fetch the web page where login and password have to be filled in. I do it so:

```
<?php
$the_url = "http://www.yahoo.com/r/l6";

$ua_s = "Opera/9.62 (Windows NT 5.1; U; En) Presto/2.1.1";

$c = curl_init($the_url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua_s);
$the_page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c); 

echo $the_page;
?>
```

But when I do that I get a blank page.

Comment: @good Please clarify what your question is

Comment: I need to fetch the login&password page on Yahoo! with help of PHP.

Comment: You know this may well violate the Yahoo! terms of service, right?

Comment: You may have an easier time if you use the login url directly: https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym

Comment: @good no need to insult people who offer free suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You could use pop access.

Comment: Look up the yahoo help. All webmail vendors (Yahoo, GMAIL, hotmail) have pop access that you can configure outlook etc to use to download your mail.  Look at the help for yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PEAR::HTTP_REQUEST](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request) it's more clean!

Or better [PEAR::Mail_IMAP](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_IMAP) this won't violating the terms of ...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option to true as the url that you supplied does a redirect.

Comment: I have added this curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); but I still can't fetch the page.

Comment: What do you fetch? This really isn't the best forum for debugging a problem.  But if you can tell us what is happening I'm sure someone will be able to help.  Edit your question to add what you are getting back and why it isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, the answers you get today may not work tomorrow, as Yahoo will

1. Be looking for this kind of TOS abuse
2. May change the structure of their application, breaking your scripts

That means if you want to do something like this, you need to teach yourself how to

1. Writes down the same cookies that a browser would
2. Sends back the same cookies as a browser would
3. Sends the same HTTP header information that a browser would

When I used to do this, I'd always use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options, and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to send back any needed headers. More info on that can be found in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

To find out what headers you'll need to send, I recommend the http://LiveHTTPHeaders extension. It'll give you the raw headers that will let you learn what's going on.

This is a non-trivial task, and you won't find a magic "just do this" answer anywhere.